# Radio Buttons are not displaying properly

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap` and have changed style of `checkbox` as:

```
<div class="radio">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="answer" required="required" 
     name="answer" id="answer" ng-value="'Nein'">
     <label for="answer">Nein</label>
</div>
```

On `IE`, previously selected radio buttons seem to display the selection incorrectly if I goes back from page to page.

`checkbox` looks like this:

[image]

whereas expected view is:

[image]

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: i am not add any fiddle, only using style-base.css and base.css

Comment: No, could you apply your code in fiddle for us to see what you've done.

Comment: Looking for a jsfiddle.net, personally I find plnkr.co to be better/easier

Comment: Remove bootstrap file and check it , It will work because in HTML5 the radio type of input is predefined

Comment: If i remove bootstarp file means other pages won't work